# P-Completeness and Reducibility

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, polynomial-time

I am taking an algorithm analysis class and am stuck on one of my homework problems and would appreciate it if I could receive some guidance.

The problem I'm stuck on is proving that the empty language and $\{0, 1\}^*$ are the only languages in **P** that are not complete for **P** with respect to polynomial-time reductions (problem 34.3-6 in CLRS 3rd edition). The first part of the problem seems fairly straightforward enough (proving the empty language criteria). However, I'm not sure where to even begin when I have to prove the criteria for $\{0, 1\}^*$. I'm NOT looking for the answer, however I would appreciate some guidance on how I can begin to think about this problem.

Comment: What is your proof for the empty language?

Comment: To expand on megas' comment, the proof that $\{0,1\}^*$ is not P-complete is the same as the proof that $\emptyset$ isn't. Don't forget that you also have to show that any other language *is* P-complete with respect to polytime reductions.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that we have covered this a couple of times already. Does somebody have a duplicate at their fingertips?

Comment: @Raphael It's included in [my answer here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/40444/9550) (that's dealing with what happens if **P$\,=\,$NP** so it talks about **NP** but applies to **P**).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks. [This](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19599/98) is also a close fit. I could not find a perfect duplicate (i.e. with answers that focus on  this issue) *and* are correct (there are a couple of answers that state P=P-complete under polytime many-one reductions). So maybe this is worth answering again, explicitly and clearly?

Comment: @Raphael Maybe we should leave it a week, since the asker explicitly asks for hints, rather than a full solution?

Comment: (Warning work with David's hint before following the link, if you're stuck it takes it a bit further) .There's also a similar question [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/if-p-np-why-wouldnt-emptyset-and-sigma-be-np-complete/7454#7454), but from the other end.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** The definition of reduction from $X$ to $Y$ requires that "yes" instances of $X$ be mapped to "yes" instances of $Y$ and "no" instances to "no" instances.

Comment: Since the question asks for hints only, I've done that. If I remember, I'll come back in a week or so (say, around 23rd March) and flesh this out into a full answer for reference purposes.

Comment: You didn't remember. :)